# How do I save this angularJS to HTML5 localStorage

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

Feel free to tell me to go away (I'm a newbie to angular and javascript), but how would I get started on saving this angularJS to localStorage? Is it something that can be done relatively painlessly by creating a saving function in the add()? I've seen that angular has its own local-storage but can this be done without that? Pen: http://codepen.io/kiddigit/pen/LZVXMV

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller("MainController", function(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'Movie Database';
    vm.searchInput = '';
    vm.shows = [
        {
            title: 'Game of Thrones',
            actor: 'Dudes',
            year: 2011,
            favorite: true
        },
        {
            title: 'Walking Dead',
            actor: 'More dudes',
            year: 2010,
            favorite: false
        },
        {
            title: 'The Goonies',
            actor: 'The Coreys',
            year: 2002,
            favorite: true
        },
        {
            title: 'Firefly',
            actor: 'Dunno',
            year: 2002,
            favorite: false
        },
        {
            title: 'Bullit',
            actor: 'McQueen',
            year: 2013,
            favorite: true
        },
    ];
    vm.orders = [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Year Ascending',
            key: 'year',
            reverse: false
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Year Descending',
            key: 'year',
            reverse: true
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title: 'Title Ascending',
            key: 'title',
            reverse: false
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            title: 'Title Descending',
            key: 'title',
            reverse: true
        }   
    ];
    vm.order = vm.orders[0];

    vm.new = {};
    vm.addShow = function() {
        vm.shows.push(vm.new);
        vm.new = {};
    };
});
```

Comment: What is your question? What do you want to save in LocalStorage ("this AngularJS" doesn't make sense. AngularJS is a framework. What you can store in LocalStorage is a string. And objects can be transformed easily to string using JSON). And no, Angular doesn't have "its own LocalStorage".

Comment: I guess there's a misunderstanding with that phrase. Angular has a wrapper module for `localStorage`. but as @JB Nizet said, it has no `localStorage` of its own.

Comment: Thanks for making that clear. I'm a obv still a little lost.

Answer (score 2):

The browser (the window object) has an object called `localStorage`, simple as that. If you want to save an object to the local storage you better stringify it first using `json`.

***Example:***

// inside your controller:

```
function saveMovie() {
  var selectedMovieString = json.stringify(this.selectedMovie); // for  example;
  localStorage.setItem("selectedMovie", selectedMovieString);
}
```

Comment: javascript language doesn't have an object `localStorage`. It is a browser window property. Try that in node.js or other js environment that doesn't have a window object and will throw errors

Comment: @AranS That's all I have to do? And that will save newly added entries?

Comment: For this domain yes, as long you don't clear the browser's cache. Oh, and there is a limit to its capacity. Learn more here:  http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: I'll have to muddle through that and see if I can make it work. Thanks for the link.